# dataset vs setAttribute performance

Tags: javascript, html, dom, attributes

I've been working with some data attributes in Javascript recently. I have been using `element.dataset.foo = "bar"` and `element.setAttribute("data-foo","bar")` interchangeably. I've heard that generally setAttribute is more reliable and that using an attribute is faster, but is that still the case with these somewhat nonstandard attributes?

Answer (score 3):

Generally `setAttribute()` is faster. You can always check [jsPerf](https://jsperf.com/html5-dataset-vs-native-setattribute).

Answer (score 3):

In terms of performance I could not tell you wich is more faster `dataset` or `element.setAttribute` but in term of support **a.k.a** reliability, `dataset` is well supported.

You can see the support table here : https://caniuse.com/#search=dataset

But in my opinion, using `dataset` produce a cleaner more readable JS code.